# Python compute all possible positions of n items in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to display a list of combinations but im having trouble making this function usable for ALL n's.
E.g. **how many ways are there to position n 1's in k positions.**

This is what I've tried to do. n = 2 and k = 6 in this situation

```
def ff():
    x_list = []
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6)[i+1::]:
            new_list = [0 for x in range(6)]
            new_list[i] = 1
            new_list[j] = 1
            x_list.append(new_list)
    return x_list
ff()
```

E.g. for n = 3

```
def ff():
    x_list = []
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6)[i+1::]:
            for k in range(6)[j+1::]:
                new_list = [0 for x in range(6)]
                new_list[i] = 1
                new_list[j] = 1
                new_list[k] = 1
                x_list.append(new_list)
    return x_list
ff()
```

However I obviously do not want to rewrite the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all possible index combinations, and set `1` just like you do:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def ff(n):
    x_list = []
    for combination in combinations(range(6), n):
        new_list = [0 for x in range(6)]
        for i in combination:
            new_list[i] = 1
        x_list.append(new_list)
    return x_list

ff(1)
ff(2)
ff(3)
```

note that in the docs they give an "example code" of how `combinations` itself is implemented, I think this will be interesting for you to read and understand!